# button click doesn't work on mobile view of the page if TailWindCSS exists

Tags: tailwind-css

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert('test')" style="pointer-events: auto;">Test</button>
```

This works on my mobile view FireFox / Chrome only if I remove TailWindCSS 3.2.7 CSS generated file from my HTML page.

I don't see any references of `pointer-events-none` in my HTML files.

How is this still not running `alert('a')` ?

TailWindCSS 3.2.7

Comment: I don't know how this is related - but when I removed the class name `inset-0` it worked.

Comment: can you check it, it's not working for me either https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77545271/button-click-doesnt-work-on-tailwind-css-on-mobile-view