# Button click doesn't work on tailwind css on mobile view

Tags: tailwind-css, alpine.js

The form transactions I send with Alpine do not trigger the button on mobile. The alert feature works, but I cannot log in.

```html
    <form  x-data="loginController"  @submit.prevent="submitForm" action="#"  class="LgnForm max-w-sm mx-auto bg-white rounded-lg pt-6 pb-8 mb-4 px-8">
    
        <div class="MskForm">
        
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label class="block text-fv-loginText text-base  mb-2">
                    Email Adresi
                </label>
                <input autofocus  x-model="fields.email.value" @blur="fields.email.validate(validationCallback)"  class="rounded-md border-fv-navColor apperance-none border  w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="username" type="text" placeholder="">
                <p class="text-red-500 text-xs  py-2"><span x-text="fields.email.error"></span></p>
            </div>

            <div class="py-2" x-data="{ show: true }">
                <label class="block text-fv-loginText text-base  mb-2">
                    Şifre
                </label>
                <div class="relative">
                    <input x-model="fields.password.value" @blur="fields.password.validate(validationCallback)"  placeholder="" :type="show ? 'password' : 'text'" class="  rounded-md  appearance-none border-fv-navColor border  w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                    <p class="text-red-500 text-xs  py-2"><span x-text="fields.password.error"></span></p>
             
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="text-red-500 text-xs  py-2"><span x-text="backendErrors"></span></p>
            <a href="#" class="inline-block align-baseline font-bold  text-sm text-fv-lightBlue  hover:opacity-50" > Şifremi Unuttum? </a>
            <button   class="block rounded-md  w-full text-center py-4 my-7  text-white bg-fv-lightBlue text-base  outline-offset-2" >
                Giriş Yap
            </button>

            <span class="flex items-center justify-center my-3">
                <span class="h-px bg-fv-navColor w-full"></span>
                <span class="font-normal text-gray-500 w-full text-center">Ya da</span>
                <span class="h-px bg-fv-navColor w-full"></span>
            </span>
            <div class="LgnSm my-4 max-w-sm flex  items-center justify-center ">
             
              
                </a>
            </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Working of the button tag in mobile view

Comment: You have a an orphan <a> tag in the last <div> in  the form. The *<div class="MskForm">* is not closed. It seems that the button has no related action